# Sharing code between applications

Tags: android

I want to create a "main" service/application which will provide
different functionalities to other applications.

According to android docs I can use elements from an application/
service in other. "A central feature of Android is that one
application can make use of elements of other applications (provided
those applications permit it). ...".
Is there any examples/documentation on this direction?
TicTacToeMain/TicTacToeLib example is not helping me because it seems
"TicTacToeLib" will be embedded in final TicTacToeMain apk file.
Also I want to ask if is possible to detect if the "main" service/
application is missing (if is missing I want to tell user to install
it, or to install it automatically).

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve this cooperation of apps. One is a [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) 
the other one is via Intents to have a look on how the Barcode reader can be invoked by other apps have a look at the documentation of the [zxing project page](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent) I think this is the most used real world example.